# Are they specifying the compilation twice in the makefiles documentation?

Tags: java, c, makefile, gnu

I am learning how to use make, and while reading the documentation saw this [example](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Variables-Simplify):

```
objects = main.o kbd.o command.o display.o \
          insert.o search.o files.o utils.o

edit : $(objects)
        cc -o edit $(objects)
main.o : main.c defs.h
        cc -c main.c
kbd.o : kbd.c defs.h command.h
        cc -c kbd.c
command.o : command.c defs.h command.h
        cc -c command.c
display.o : display.c defs.h buffer.h
        cc -c display.c
insert.o : insert.c defs.h buffer.h
        cc -c insert.c
search.o : search.c defs.h buffer.h
        cc -c search.c
files.o : files.c defs.h buffer.h command.h
        cc -c files.c
utils.o : utils.c defs.h
        cc -c utils.c
clean :
        rm edit $(objects)
```

My question is on the edit target. I am using make with Java so it may be a compilation difference I'm not aware of, but when I just specify the objects once on the first line of edit it goes to each of the rules I set up for those objects and runs the compilation, so why does the `edit` rule have another line to compile those objects? Is the documentation just compiling it twice or is there a specific difference?

Comment: `cc -c` compiles.  `cc -o` links.  The documentation for `cc` explains.  (*"I am using make with Java so it may be a compilation difference I'm not aware of ..."* - Why are you using Make with Java?  Ant, Maven, Gradle, etc are better build tools for Java than Make.  Since about the year 2000 :-) )

Comment: I want to be able to quickly compile classes when working in vim, I looked at Ant and saw how syntax heavy it was because of XML so didn't really want to touch it too much since I wanted something simple. Thinking about it now though you only have to set up build tools once and edit them occasionally, and Gradle looks really nice so I'll check that out tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: @StephenC to be more precise, `cc` with the `-c` option compiles; `cc` without the `-c` option (or any other option that modifies the type of output) links.  The presence (or absence) of `-o` is irrelevant to the type of output you get... it only defines the name of the output file.

Comment: The reason that make is not so good with Java is because make was designed with an environment where "building" an input file gives one (or a small number) of well-known output files, whose names can be easily determined based on the input file name.  Java is not like that: the output files might not have names which are related to the input file name.  There are other reasons as well, such as downloading imported files automatically, etc. which make doesn't do (unless you write rules to do it).

Comment: After taking a look at Gradle it is definitely more suited for java files, thanks @StephenC!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking another look at the code, I realized that they are creating an executable from the created objects, pretty cool haha!

EDIT:

If you are trying to use make for java projects, consider using build tools such as gradle, it makes compilation and testing much easier.